# second column of grid view accept only numbers in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a grid view..in my second column of grid view i want to enter only numerics

so i given code like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, 
                                           DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            int i;

            if (!int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(e.FormattedValue), out i))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                label1.Text ="please enter numeric";
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

but before doing this i want to check wethar this column contains any value or not? if any value contains then only i want to check wethar this value is numeric or not? how i can do this?
any help is very appreciable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check for a blank string first, so something like:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        int i;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue)  && !int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(e.FormattedValue), out i))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            label1.Text ="please enter numeric";
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no sir ..by mistake...i will check again and let u know

Comment: your question says "Second column", but checked the third - what does the debugger tell you? Are both your `if` statements ever evaluated?

Comment: if i want to check 2 and 3 column then i can write  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 and e.columnindex==2)

Comment: If you want to check changes that are in column 2 or column 3, then it would be `(e.ColumnIndex == 1 || e.ColumnIndex == 2)`